# How do I handle given custom exception?

Tags: java

I have an Exception class which has to be used in my coding. I am not able to display the message that the exception class contains when constructed. Here is the given exception class.

```
public class MonthException extends Exception
{
    public MonthException()
    {
        super("Invalid value for month.");
    }

    public MonthException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }

    public MonthException(int month)
    {
        super("\n" + month + " is an invalid month number.");
    }
}
```

So far I have written the following code:

```
try
{
     String[] date = args[0].split("/");
     String month = date[0];
     String day = date[1];
     MonthException exception = new MonthException();
    if (Integer.parseInt(date[0]) < 1 || Integer.parseInt(date[0]) > 12)
    {
        throw new MonthException();
    }
    catch(MonthException exception)
    {
        System.out.println(MonthException.getMessage());
    } 
}
```

Comment: `public class Exception extends Exception` Really?

Comment: What does that print statement print instead? (Although I have a feeling the answer is "nothing, it won't compile" by that sort of information (and the compile error) is critical to the question)

Comment: You can remove the line `MonthException exception = new MonthException();` as it is not doing anything. Just make sure you construct your `new MonthException("some thing wrong")` with a message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have written there makes **absolutely no sense**. What should be the point of throwing an exception in a try-catch-block? So don't mess arround with exceptions if you do not even understand object oriented programming and do the following...:

```
int month = Integer.parseInt(date[0]);
if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
    System.out.println(month + " is not a valid month");
    return;
}
```

Nevertheless, this is how you would use an exception:

```
public static int getMonth(String str) throws InvalidMonthException {
    int month = Integer.parseInt(str);
    if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
        throw new InvalidMonthException(month);
    }
    return month;
}
```

And then in the method:

```
int month;
try {
    month = getMonth(date[0]);
} catch (InvalidMonthException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage);
    return;
}
System.out.println(month); // Or whatever you want to do with your month.........
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try
{
    String[] date = args[0].split("/");
    String month = date[0];
    String day = date[1];
    //This is no need
    //MonthException exception = new MonthException();
    if (Integer.parseInt(date[0]) < 1 || Integer.parseInt(date[0]) > 12)
    {
        throw new MonthException(Integer.parseInt(date[0]));
    }
    catch(MonthException exception)
    {
        System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
    } 
}
```

Try this

Comment: This will give only the month number.

Comment: It should give you this kind of message: "\n" + month + " is an invalid month number." because you have such a constructor, with Integer.parseInt(date[0]) it will choose appropriate constructor with int

Answer (score 0):

Try with: 
...

```
catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
...
```

Comment: That will print ("Invalid value for month.") but I want to print ("\n" + month + " is an invalid month number.")

Comment: Then you should use the constructor that initializes the exception with the message you want.

Comment: I tried throw new MonthException(month); It gives only the month number not full message

Comment: This answer is missing the problem that `new MonthException()` is not being constructed with an error message, so the call to `e.getMessage()` here will return `null`

Answer (score 0):

If you define your own **MonthException**  then throw it as soon as something invalid happens, this will propagate the exception, which must either be rethrown by the invoking method or catch it

Example:

```
class MyException extends Exception{}

class Test{
    public void getMonatPayment(int index) throws MyException {
        if(index < 0){
             throw new MyException("Some msg");
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
class MainImplementation{
    public static void main(String[] args){
         Test t = new Test();
         try{
             t.getMonatPayment(-5);
          } catch(MyException ex){ //dosomething usefull}
    }
}
```

or

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MyException{
         Test t = new Test();
             t.getMonatPayment(-5);
    }
```